# Internalizating content heavy pages into messagefiles seem cumbersome in play2?

Tags: internationalization, playframework-2.0

Internalization in Play2 can be done with `Message.get("home.title")` and language files. What about when you internalizate a page full of textual content and not just one specific header or link?

For example doing *Messagefile* for a long page representing e.g. product info:

```
_First header_ 
Some paragraphs of text
...
_Tenth header_
Tenth paragraph and more text*
```

**Messagefile**

**a)**
`product.info = "<many paragraphs of text including headers>"`

*or* splitting one page into html elements

**b)**

```
   product.info.h1 = "<first header>"
   product.info.p1 = "<first para>"
   product.info.p2 = "<2nd para>"
```

For me both solutions doesn't sound right. In first having a vast value for a single key seems bad convention and in latter separating a single page into dozens of keys doesn't sound good either.

Big websites often follow the convention *www.site.com/**en-us**/product/1* of having the language in the URL. So the question is, how do i do in this way and is doing in this way a better way at all? I could easily end up not just translating to dozen languages but doing also dozen times layout changes.

I could use global codesnippets using *Messagefile* for elements that have a little text and doesn't change often e.g. navigation `/view/global/header/somenavbar.scala.html` but then i end up only having a complex folder structure.

Another way, a best practise, in Play 2 for internalization than messagefile?

Comment: I don't what could be the best practise, but have you considered having one static HTML page per language and include the right one according to the current langugage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the Joscha Feth's solution in [play_authenticate Java sample](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage).

There are templates for emails in 3 languages for *email confirmation*, *password reseting* etc.

Template for each 'type' of email && each language is kept in single file ie:

- [_password_reset_en.scala.html](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/views/account/email/_password_reset_en.scala.html)
- [_password_reset_de.scala.html](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/views/account/email/_password_reset_de.scala.html)
- [_password_reset_pl.scala.html](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/views/account/email/_password_reset_pl.scala.html)
- [_verify_email_en...](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/views/account/email/_verify_email_en.scala.html) etc

And for each 'type' there is an 'parent' template, which contains a condition (common Scala's `match` [check the **Tags** section of template doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaTemplateUseCases)) which returns rendered view depending on detected language:

- [password_reset.scala.html](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/views/account/email/password_reset.scala.html)

Finally, yes, at the beginning I also thought that some kind of madness, but believe me, that technique can be useful. There's field for further improvements I think. Maybe it would be better to move the language conditioning to the controller, hm I think that depends on many factors and it will be great if you'll find a time to investigate this topic.

Comment: Yes! This is something that i may call "a best practice", simple and working and i'm not thinking this as "madness" :)

Comment: @Thomson256 well, I was writing about last file in the set - containing match statement, just when you adding new language you have to remember to update it every time. It was better if it was recognised automatically, generally I had no time and didn't need to use more sophisticated methods, but I think that's the mentioned field for improvements.